# Suppose I reach to this page customer/account/login/, after I click on "Sign In" button and i found referer feature not working :(

Tags: url, redirect, page, key, referral

How to echo or print the referer url(history page) from where I reached to that login page.
I have to implement something that after login user should not reach to dashboard instead he should re-direct to the same page from where he came after login. 
Some blogs says its an inbuilt feature of magento , but i don't why this inbuilt feature is not working in my case and also i need to know the flow of the referer/key variable and its implementation to be successful.
I want to know the proper working or some good tutorial link for that referer implementation.

I tried this 
My research page - https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-referer-url-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a plugin to intercept the controller that does the login.

di.xml

```
<type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="my_plugin_after_login" type="\MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

And the plugin class

```
<?php

/**
 *
 */
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin;

/**
 *
 */
class LoginPostPlugin
{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
 */
protected $redirectInterface;
/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

  /**
   * LoginPostPlugin constructor.
   * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirectInterface
   * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   */
   public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirectInterface,
      \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
  ) {
      $this->redirectInterface = $redirectInterface;
      $this->logger = $logger;
  }

  /**
    * Change redirect after login to home instead of dashboard.
    *
    * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
    */
   public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
    $result
   ) {
    $result->setPath($this->redirectInterface->getRefererUrl());
    return $result;
  }
}
```

The method **getRefererUrl()** from the interface **\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface** help you with that.